# HMVC on CodeIgniter 3 not working - getting 404

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

I 'm trying to set up modularity on my CI 3 installation, but seems not working. I'm using wiredesignz package found [here](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/downloads) under the "Branches" tab.

The steps I did:

1. Copied MY_Loader & MY_Router in application/core
2. Copied MX folder in application/third_party
3. Copied this line of code in application/development/config.php ( I have moved config.php under development folder )

   // set location for modules
   $config['modules_locations'] = array(
       APPPATH.'modules/' => '../../modules/',
   );
4. Created

   application
       - modules
       -- controllers
       --- Test.php
       -- models
       -- views
       --- test.php

with my Test.php like this

```
class Test extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('test');
    }
}
```

just to check that is working ok, but when I hit on my browser localhost/myapp/test, I get a 404 error.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `.htaccess`? Have you tried with `localhost/myapp/index.php/test`?

Comment: @Tpojka I have tried both ways, nothing works

Comment: Yup, you have been extending CI_Controller instead MX_Controller. Check one answer bellow.

Comment: Did you obey all 12 installation points from [here](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/overview#markdown-header-modular-extensions-installation)?

Comment: Check your `routes.php` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to put the controllers and views in test folder inside the modules folder?

Means something like that

application/modules/test/controllers/Test.php

Comment: Yes I had forgotten to create the 'test' folder under modules. Silly mistake by me.. anyway thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 2):

HMVC Modules folder for Codeigniter 3
[How to implement HMVC in codeigniter 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30865998/how-to-implement-hmvc-in-codeigniter-3-0/31008225#31008225)

[image: codeigniter 3 hmvc tree reqire files]
I tested works

Answer (score 0):

Try change CI_Controller to this MX_Controller

```
class Test extends MX_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('test');
    }
}
```

But I think you also need sub modules folder example

```
modules => admin => controllers
modules => admin => controllers => Test.php
modules => admin => models
modules => admin => views
modules => admin => views => test.php
```

Make sure you configure your routes

Example:

```
$route['test'] = "admin/test/index";
```

Comment: you do not need to set modules path in config

Comment: make sure you set your routes also example in my answer

Comment: I believe that the documentation says that you need to set the modules path inside config.php

Comment: I have also set the routing like this but still no luck

Comment: This routing you said is used if you want to create admin pages/controllers. This Test controller is a simple testing one.. however I have set up my routing like this but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines in application/third_party/MX/Loader.php after line 307,

```html
protected function _ci_object_to_array($object) 
 {
    return is_object($object) ? get_object_vars($object) : $object;
    }
```

Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone still has this issue, even though the file/folder structure is correct, in my case, and it took me a few days to figure it out, there were 2 additional issues:

1. This I am not 100% sure, but if I remember correctly I could not see subfolders so I had to chmod 755 on them again
2. This was the killer: my file name was with lowercase ("welcome.php" instead of "Welcome.php") for the controller. Once I renamed the file with uppercase I got rid of 404 and everything worked.