# How to implement HMVC in codeigniter 3.0?

Tags: hmvc, codeigniter-hmvc

Currently I'm using `codeigniter` version 3.0. I want to know how to implement HMVC structure in it, can anyone help?

Comment: download hmvc from https://github.com/Crypt/Codeigniter-HMVC 
follow the steps mentioned "Modular Extensions installation" steps on readme.md file. i hope it will be solve ur issue.

Answer (score 16):

codeigniter 3 hmvc modules folder for:

https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/downloads

1- Download files and copy C.i.3.0 forder in application

2- .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

3- create /application/modules

4-  /application/modules/welcome create in  controllers, models, views

5- Create /application/modules/welcome/controllers/Welcome.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

enjoy :)

> IMPORTANT :  'controllers' and 'models' initials files in the folder should be large. 'views' of files per folder in the letter should be small

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this @Limitless isa

Comment: Link is dead now

Comment: New Link: https://github.com/brianwozeniak/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

Answer (score 5):

1 Step : Download
https://github.com/Crypt/Codeigniter-HMVC/tree/master/core
Copy  MY_Loader.php , MY_Router.php

paste in

> application/core

directory

2 : step  Download https://github.com/Crypt/Codeigniter-HMVC/tree/master/libraries

MX folder

Paste in

> application/third_party

3 :Step   modules/routes.php

> $route['default_controller'] = 'index.php/Home/Home/index';

4: step  create new folder (Home) in directory application/modules

5: step application/modules/Home  in    new Folder (controllers ,models,views)

Directory Structure e.g.

__application

__modules

```
 __Home

    __controllers

       __Home.php 

    __modules

       __home.php

    __views

       __home.php
```

6 : step application/modules/Home/controllers   in (Home.php)

```
<?php
class Home extends MY_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

public  function index()
    {
        echo "WELOME TO HERE";
    }




}

?>
```

Comment: I think under modules/home/model folder will be there note modules/home/module . correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: we can keep model folder outside modules folder (which is already present)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the template to understand how to use HMVC in codeigniter. You can also use the Rest-API with HMVC Module.

Download the full HMVC module:

https://github.com/salimmansoori1994/full_ci_set

Answer (score 0):

Use the new version from here.
https://github.com/N3Cr0N/HMVC

original source not updated since many years and it gives errors.

Installing process is there on readme file.