# Do codigniter 3.1.7 support hmvc? I tried but no luck

Tags: codeigniter, php-7

From the very first answer of this 
[How to implement HMVC in codeigniter 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30865998/how-to-implement-hmvc-in-codeigniter-3-0][1]) I tried all steps with codigniter 3.7.1 but no luck. I am still getting 404.

```
$config['modules_locations'] = array(
    APPPATH.'modules/' => '../modules/',
);
```

Then I tried putting the above code in application/config/config.php but still 404

Comment: I tried HMVC with codigniter 2.2.6 with got successful result in first attempt followed the same url as in above question.

Comment: It all works fine for me must be something to do with your setup you may need to add this in to your my loaded https://pastebin.com/vNUhJCss

Comment: Sorry But still not working.... :'(

Comment: Found the error, I renamed applicaton/controllers to applicaton/controllers_old to check if new controller is working. I renamed it back to controllers and now it is working fine thnx.